# Output of $cwd for csh shell ambigious

Tags: csh

My script is in this folder :  `/home/folder`. When I run the script within folder (ie /home/folder) and do echo $cwd within the script, it shows /home as the cwd. However, if I go to /home/folder and do $cwd on the commond prompt it shows /home/folder. Why is there this difference?

Answer (score 2):

The script you are running may be changing the value of a variable $cwd to the current directory from which it is called. Please provide the code in the script you are running, this will be more helpful for us to provide answer.

Comment: right also be aware a script that runs with #!/bin/csh begins with evaluating your .cshrc, so the change could be there as well